# Python to check existence of nested JSON key-value

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have JSON in given format and my goal is to determine if the key-value pair of

"name" : "Important1", "name" : "Important2", "name" : "Important3" exists under "TAG3" or not?

I need to do this via Python. Any suggestions? I have tried various examples suggested but none of them is able to parse the given example.

```json
{
  "BASE": {
    "TAG1": [
      {
        "attr": {
          "name": "val1",
          "place": "val1"
        },
        "r1": 65535,
        "r2": 444
      },
      {
        "attr": {
          "name": "Important1",
          "place": "RPlace"
        },
        "r1": 65535,
        "r2": 109
      },
      {
        "attr": {
          "name": "Important2",
          "place": "GPlace"
        },
        "r1": 65535,
        "r2": 453
      },
      {
        "attr": {
          "name": "Important3",
          "place": "BPlace"
        },
        "r1": 65535,
        "r2": 109
      }
    ],
    "my-id": 2412922,
    "TAG2": [
      {
        "attr": {
          "name": "val1",
          "place": "val1"
        },
        "r1": 65535,
        "r2": 444
      },
      {
        "attr": {
          "name": "Important1",
          "place": "RPlace"
        },
        "r1": 65535,
        "r2": 109
      },
      {
        "attr": {
          "name": "Important2",
          "place": "GPlace"
        },
        "r1": 65535,
        "r2": 453
      },
      {
        "attr": {
          "name": "Important3",
          "place": "BPlace"
        },
        "r1": 65535,
        "r2": 109
      }
    ],
    "TAG3": [
      {
        "name": "POSITION",
        "place": "POSITION",
        "type": "M96"
      },
      {
        "name": "val1",
        "place": "val1"
      },
      {
        "name": "Important1",
        "place": "RPlace"
      },
      {
        "name": "Important2",
        "place": "GPlace"
      },
      {
        "name": "Important3",
        "place": "BPlace"
      }
    ],
    "out-box": {
      "r1": [
        6.2,
        7.3
      ],
      "r2": [
        6.2,
        7.3
      ]
    },
    "t1": "hldsadh1",
    "t2": 0,
    "t3": 20,
    "string-attr": [
      1,
      16
    ],
    "r1-chk": 342,
    "my-size": 34,
    "where": [
      2.9,
      54.9
    ],
    "sometag": 2,
    "revision": 0,
    "nodata": [
      0,
      0
    ],
    "noscale": [
      0.001,
      0.001
    ],
    "time-val": 3444
  }
}
```

I tried using below function but due to my limited python knowledge i am kind of stuck

```
def keys_exists(element, *keys):
    """
    Check if *keys (nested) exists in `element` (dict).
    """
    if type(element) is not dict:
        raise AttributeError('keys_exists() expects dict as first argument.')
    if len(keys) == 0:
        raise AttributeError('keys_exists() expects at least two arguments, one given.')

    _element = element
    for key in keys:
        try:
            _element = _element[key]
        except KeyError:
            return False
    return True
```

If I store the JSON I shared in variable called `data1`, then I am trying to use above function as

```
keys_exists(data1, "BASE", "TAG3", "name")))
```

Please feel free to discard my version and share your own as well.

Comment: Can you show what you *have* tried.

Comment: @blueteeth - I am pretty new to python and depending on trial and search. I have updated the question but you are welcome to share a completely new approch

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem to be iterating over everything rather than trying to extract what you need. I would create a function to get the all the names for a tag, then you can check whether specific names exist or not.

```py
data = json.loads("""
<the json string goes here>
""")

def get_names_by_tag(tag):
    return [item["name"] for item in data["BASE"][tag]]

tag3_names = get_names_by_tag("TAG3")
# tag3_names = ['POSITION', 'val1', 'Important1', 'Important2', 'Important3']

important_names = ["Important1", "Important2", "Important3"]

if all(important_name in tag3_names for important_name in important_names):
    # do something
```

Comment: With this code i am getting below error.                                                                     
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 137, in <module>
    tag3_names = get_names_by_tag("TAG3")
  File "main.py", line 135, in get_names_by_tag
    return [item["name"] for item in data["BASE"][tag]]
TypeError: string indices must be integers

Comment: Have loaded the json as a dict?

Comment: I am very new to python. I just assigned data = ''' <the json data> '''. Could you elaborate a bit more?

Comment: You need to load the json string into a python object. See https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html#json.loads (and my edit)

Comment: Thanks. I think its working now. And just to confirm at this moment, the code is checking if key value pair of "name" : "Important1", "name" : "Important2", "name" : "Important3" is present under "TAG3". I believe the "all" keyword is like "AND" condition. What is there for "OR" condition i.e to check any one of name" : "Important1", "name" : "Important2", "name" : "Important3" is present under "TAG3"?

Comment: You got it already. `all(...)` is basically AND-ing everything in the loop. `any(...)` is the equivalent for OR. :)